# Flipping 3D Gameobjects in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, game-engine

Is there a way to Flip (Mirror) a 3D GameObject in Unity3d?

I want to flip one of the 3D GameObjects Using  Unity Game-engine capability

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, flipping an object is not that hard actually. Here's two snippets of my code that achieve this (I left out the obvious boilerplate that grabs the mesh reference):

```
    public bool flipX = true;
    public bool flipY;
    public bool flipZ;


 void Flip()
    {
        if (mesh == null) return;
        Vector3[] verts = mesh.vertices;
        for (int i = 0; i < verts.Length; i++)
        {
            Vector3 c = verts[i];
            if (flipX) c.x *= -1;
            if (flipY) c.y *= -1;
            if (flipZ) c.z *= -1;
            verts[i] = c;
        }

        mesh.vertices = verts;
        if (flipX ^ flipY ^ flipZ) FlipNormals();
    }
```

One important detail is that depending on the axis configuration you might need to flip face normals. This is achieved by reversing the order in which verts are referenced in the triangles array:

```
    void FlipNormals()
    {
        int[] tris = mesh.triangles;
        for (int i = 0; i < tris.Length / 3; i++)
        {
            int a = tris[i * 3 + 0];
            int b = tris[i * 3 + 1];
            int c = tris[i * 3 + 2];
            tris[i * 3 + 0] = c;
            tris[i * 3 + 1] = b;
            tris[i * 3 + 2] = a;
        }
        mesh.triangles = tris;
    }
```

Comment: i want to upvote your answer but i still new and got 11 points

Comment: just adding that you have to do mesh.RecalculateBounds and mesh.RecalculateNormals if you also flipped the normals

Answer (score 3):

You can scale the object by `X` = `-1` or `Y` = `-1` or `Z` = `-1` in inspector. According to the axis you want to mirror the object.

By code you can do this by:

```
transform.localScale += new Vector3(-transform.localScale.x, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);
```

for mirroring by the x-axis for example.

This is working for simple objects. If the object is animated this will cause a strange behaviour.

Comment: This causes negative effects and modifying the mesh like [zambari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51100522/9677569) is better. Although both answers deserve upvote.

Comment: Yes, the right solution dependents on the use case. The use case is not mentioned in the question. I would recommend my (simple) solution only for basic objects with non-complex shaders.

Comment: If object is animated or uses basic colliders or uses normal textures or (a lot of stuff) can go wrong because of the computational mess it does to mesh in question. You cannot even scale simple cube like that, it will already produce a warning telling you "BoxColliders does not support negative scale or size."